# The first or second conditional after "predict"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, collocations

What's the difference in meaning?

> 1. Some scientists predict that if everyone in the world lived like an American, our fossil fuel supply would last for just fifteen more years.

Or:

> 2. Some scientists predict that if everyone in the world lives like an American, our fossil fuel supply will last for just fifteen more years.

*Predict* means *to say something will happen, before it happens*. Then, is there any room for a hypothetical situation as in Sentence 1?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the degree of likelihood or plausibility the speaker is choosing to convey.

> If everyone in the world lives ...

suggests that the speaker thinks this is something that could happen. Not necessarily that they think it likely, but that it is still a possibility.

> If everyone in the world lived ...

suggests they think it unlikely to happen: not impossible, but less likely (more 'counter-factual') than the first case.